# jQuery JSON Flickr images not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Really killing me.

I've got a page that uses jQuery's getJSON method to snag some photos of Flickr. Works everywhere but IE. What am I missing?

test page: http://test.dhut.ch/

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/RzkzY/2/

```
 function imgBuilder(data){
    $.each(data.photos.photo,function(i,rPhoto){
        var base   = 'http://farm' + rPhoto.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + rPhoto.server + '/' + rPhoto.id + '_' + rPhoto.secret,
            thumb  = base + '_m.jpg',
            medium = base + '.jpg',
            large  = base + '_b.jpg',
            imageM = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ medium +'"><img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + rPhoto.title + '"/></a>',
            imageL = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" ' + 'title="' + rPhoto.title + '" href="'+ large +'"><img src="' + thumb + '" alt="' + rPhoto.title + '"/></a>';

        $(imageM).appendTo("#test");
    });
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ac08dd724a859d7fb3192293595eb496&user_id=26545877%40N04&tags=terminal+5&per_page=25&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&auth_token=72157629922435489-4d437791b153803b&api_sig=9203d027009eb268adf9e790852a0e28", imgBuilder);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JSONP.  Add the `jsoncallback` parameter to the query string.

Comment: When I add &jsoncallback=? to the string (built by Flickr's API explorer) it returns jsonFlickrApi({"stat":"fail", "code":96, "message":"Invalid signature"})